# what is the difference between class and Class ? in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs3

i was just writing some code and wrote :

```
public Class start extends SimpleButton
```

I thought this would be 100% right but it gave errors

```
1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute public, not Class.

1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.
```

I open some previous actionscript and wrote in this one

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before leftbrace.
```

So MY QUESTION is that what is the difference between Class and class

Atleast i am sure that for both (class and Class) there is some type of definition

It will be kind of you if you will answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Class** is a type name similar to your classes or SimpleButton. This is special class that is created for each class definition in a program.

See documentation for details http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html

The **class** is an keyword. You use it for declare your own classes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html). Class is a type in AS3 and every object has an instance of Class, similar to Type in some other languages. The lowercase variant is a keyword whereas the camel-case version is an object type. It holds information about functions and fields as well as constructor information.

Comment: This is incorrect. In AS3, every object extends `Object`, as with other languages. The `Class` datatype is used to describe actual classes, rather than instances of classes. An instance of a `Class` object has no relation whatsoever to `Class`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the document at Adobe and read "Every object is an instance of the Class class" rather than the correct "Every Class object is an instance of the Class class."

Comment: Yeah. Basically, the `Class` datatype allows you to pass around specific Classes as if they were variables. In Flex's `ViewNavigator`, when you want to move to a new `View`, you pass a `Class` object (`newView:Class` is the argument) and the ViewNavigator is what instantiates the object (calling `new newView()`)